# OAuth2 in memory token loss due to server application restart

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, access-token

I encountered this problem in test stage of my application. Client set expiration date of token for very long time (19 years or so), so we wouldn't request new token often during tests. But After a while it came out that token has already expired (after random time).

The problem was server application being restarted/updated, resulting in in-memory tokens lost and rendering my simple check for expires_in not working:

```
if (_currentToken.ExpirationDate < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1))
{
    _currentToken = GetToken();
}
```

How would I secure such scenario? It might as well happen on production, but hopefully more rarely due to less application restarts and shorter token time. Unfortunately I don't have an access to server side authorization settings and tokens won't be persited in any storage.

I would like avoid calling some dummy action on server to check if it returns `401 unauthorized` before every action.

Comment: What happens if you call GetToken() before expiration date?

Comment: It will simply request new token from auth server.

Comment: The call it and use instead of the previous key

Comment: So you suggest to just get new token before each request? it kind of defeats the whole purpose of OAuth

Comment: Not before each request. Do it once, and refresh the key, expiration date at once, for a longer new period of time. You should be able to do it any time for security reasons, at least because the key itself can be compromised theoretically or practically.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. I cannot rely 100% on expires_in, because token might not be expired yet, but still not be available on server (due to application restart). I am trying to find an elegant way to know when it is gone and must be issued again.

Comment: The elegant way is to send the request and not rely on the expiraton at all. If key is expired, the request will fail regardless of your logic in C#. The failure will be likely: Not Authorized HTTP 401. If request failed, then start the keys refresh procedure according to used OAuth2 procedure. You will get new key, refresh token and expire time. As expire time is not that useful, just not use it in the code.

Comment: To summarise. Do request. If request failed with any authorisation failure, then refresh your tokens and repeat the request. Many servers provide the tokens for 24 hours and even less. So refreshing the tokens is a very usual operation in OAuth2.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's server side's responsibility to validate token and decide whether the request with token could access specific protected resources . So as @armagedescu suggested , just send the token when performing token request , server side will check the claims like expire time , issuer ...  and also check the signature . If token is expired , it will return 401 status code , and [the OAuth 2.0 bearer token spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3) adds `error`, `error_description`, and `error_uri` attributes to the `WWW-Authenticate` header for reporting additional error information :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="example",
                   error="invalid_token",
                   error_description="The access token expired"
```

Then on client side you can check the errors , and refresh access token to perform another token request .